# don't have apk in Bin and cannot build app in monodevelop when update Mono for Android 4.1

Tags: xamarin.android

After update Mono for Android from 4.0 -> 4.1 ,I have problems:

1. In Visual Studio : when I start application , it doesn't run application in emulator(I only see message notification at left corner Build successful!) and I cannot see .apk file in Bin
2. In Mono develope :When I build this app it have error  Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\BackendBindings\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019)

Does anyone know what might generate these errors?

Answer (score -1):

In VS, you probably need to turn on "Deploy" for your project:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_for_Android_4.1.0#Non-modal_Deployment

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i turned on"Deploy" in project,It still not run